# prevent double click button with asp.net javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello I'm trying to prevent double click on a button with javascript plus aspnet application but it seems not working does anyone know what is the problem? here my code

asp.net

```
<asp:Button ID="SalvarArquivo" Class="btn btn-primary col-xs-5 cancel" Text="Enviar Arquivo" runat="server" OnClick="SalvarArquivo_Click" OnClientClick="BloquearBotao(this);" UseSubmitBehavior="false"/>
```

javascript funciont

```
function BloquearBotao(botao) {
        botao.disable = true;
        return true;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, I think that you need to make a slight modification to your BloquearBotao function:

```
 function BloquearBotao(botao) {
    botao.disabled = true;
    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery:

```
 $(document).dblclick(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```